Expo run:ios - No bundle url present
I'm encountering this "NO bundle URL Present" error when running npx expo:run ios --device 'mydevice'. I've tried various types of solutions and none of them work. I've practically tried everything that's on StackOverflow and still nothing... Does anyone have an alternative solution or has anyone experienced this error before?

My dependencies:
{
    "dependencies": {
      "@expo/config": "^8.1.1",
      "@expo/metro-config": "^0.10.0",
      "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
      "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
      "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.75.0-main",
      "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
      "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
      "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
      "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
      "@realm/react": "^0.6.2",
      "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.8",
      "expo": "~50.0.7",
      "expo-localization": "~14.8.3",
      "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
      "expo-system-ui": "~2.9.3",
      "i18next": "^23.7.20",
      "metro-source-map": "^0.80.5",
      "react": "18.2.0",
      "react-i18next": "^14.0.1",
      "react-native": "0.73.6",
      "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
      "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.4",
      "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
      "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.11.0",
      "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
      "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
      "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.8.2",
      "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
      "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.2",
      "realm": "^12.6.2",
      "styled-components": "^6.1.8",
      "uuid": "^9.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
      "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
      "@types/react-native": "^0.73.0",
      "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
      "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.2",
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.2",
      "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
      "eslint": "^8.50.0",
      "eslint-config-universe": "^12.0.0",
      "metro-config": "^0.80.8",
      "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
      "prettier": "^3.2.5",
      "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
      "typescript": "^5.3.3"
    },
}

metro.config:
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

module.exports = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

I've done almost everything, deleted the ios folder, ran pod install again, executed it, and the error persists. Could anyone help?

For anyone facing this issue, it's a hostname problem with the port. Check your machine's IP and enter it manually, or set which IP the metro is running on port 8081

Could you please describe your solution with the port in more detail? Enter manually where?

@mediafreakch are you using expo? If so, open it, click on your app and something should appear to enter the expo url manually, get your IP and enter h t t p://seu-ip:8081

Yes we're using expo, but not the expo app. Meanwhile we pinned down the issue to an update of ESET Endpoint Security for OSX. As a workaround we disabled ESETs network access protections (firewall) for now.

Check out this issue here for reference:
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/29512
But basically the problem is that your Mac and your IPHONE are not on the same WIFI or network.
So make sure you are on the same WIFI and you should be good to go, you don't even need to restart the Metro server.
Let me know if that helped anyone!

This error seems to indicate that the Metro server is down. Please run one of the following in the command screen in the project directory;
yarn start, react-native start, expo start, npx expo start.
Then compile iOS by pressing i.
Or by opening side command screen
yarn run ios, react-native run-ios, expo run:ios, npx expo run:ios
you can run it with any of these commands.
Do not forget to close the application open on the phone or simulator.
